# How to use the Entity Framework `ValueComparer<T>`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a ASP.NET 3.1 project.
The class `EmployeeSummary` contains a public property `string[] Roles`

```
public string[] Roles { get; set; }
```

and has the **value converter** set for the array of strings:

```
          modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSummary>()
                .Property(e => e.Roles)
                .HasConversion(v => string.Join(",", v),
                    v => v.Split(new[]
                        {
                            ","
                        }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .ToList()
                        .Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        .ToArray());
```

I'm getting the following`System.InvalidOperationException` indicating that I have no **value comparer** set:

```
The property 'Roles' on entity type 'EmployeeSummary' is a collection or enumeration type 
with a value converter but with no value comparer. 
Set a value comparer to ensure the collection/enumeration elements are compared correctly.
```

My approach was to add (likewise to the examples in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers))

- A `var valueComparer` in class `EmployeeSummary`
- Set to `new ValueComparer<string[]>` instead of `new ValueComparer<List<int>>`
- Check if two arrays are identical.
  This however doesn't work:

```
        public string[] Roles { get; set; }

        private var valueComparer = new ValueComparer<string[]>(
             (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2));
```

with a message that the constructor cannot be resolved. Is this the right way to go, or how can I solve this error message?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `ValueComparer` in the method `HasConversion`.

A working example for this would be:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeSummary>()
            .Property(e => e.Roles)
            .HasConversion(
                v => string.Join(',', v),
                v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
                    .Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    .ToArray(), new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
                    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                    c => c.ToList()));
```